# CakePHP Passwords Migration to Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to migrate hashed passwords from CakePHP 1.3 over to Laravel 5.6? I am in the midst of a framework migration at the moment.

Comment: Well you can do it of course, create your own hash driver and use it instead of stock `bcrypt` one.

Comment: According to [this](https://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Authentication.html) cake 1.3 uses sha1 by default - If that is the case with your current setup I would recommend detecting if the hash is sha1 [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982059/testing-if-string-is-sha1-in-php) then changing it to bcrypt (force a change) for better security

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can

CakePHP 1.3 use ( Salt+Sha1(password) )

make laravel hash password (old salt + sha1  )