# How detect a Git SHA ID in a text

Tags: git, commit, sha

A Git SHA ID looks like this one `351e11dac558a764ba83f89c6598151d2dbaf904`, it is a long hex number. But how should it be detected in a text? Search for "words" which only contain 0-9,a-f and have a length of at least 20 characters? **But how to distinguish SHA IDs from normal words**?

Comment: A SHA-1 hash is guaranteed to be 160-bits long.  Since each character represents a nibble, the string is 40 characters long.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468370/a-regex-to-match-a-sha1 help here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your approach will work.  Remember, though, SHA1 is a general algorithm (not git specific), so it's possible your text could contain other SHA1 hashes in it which will also be 40 character hex strings.